# Upgrade Ubuntu from 12.04 to 13.10

Tags: updates

How will I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.1 internally without the iso file . Please help .

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct upgrade path. There are a couple of choices:

- You can upgrade to 12.10 and then 13.04 and then 13.10 but that's a fair amount of bandwidth... Or,
- You can wait a 21 days for 14.04 to be released. This is another LTS release and you should be able to upgrade directly from 12.04.